# How to set format "dd/mm/yy" in NestJS without time

Tags: date, nestjs

I'm learning NestJS, i't so powerful but i have some problem

That's type DATE format like DateTime

How can i convert to the the format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Thank for your help

Comment: When returning a serialized entity from a controller? Can you add some more context, ideally a code snippet?

Comment: i connect to database and it look like code first  and in database it always type timestamp without timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably look at [Serialization](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) section in documentation.

So if you have `UserEntity` with `dateOfBirth` that you want to format like date, you should probably use `@Transform` annotation.

Maybe something like this:

`@Transform(dateOfBirth => moment(dateOfBirth).format('DD/MM/YY'))`

Full example:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'; 
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

@Entity() 
export class AAA { 
   
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() 
   id: number; 

   @Column({ length: 500 }) 
   name: string; 

   @Transform(date1 => moment(date1).format('DD/MM/YY'))
   @Column() 
   date1:Date; 
}
```

Controller:

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@Get()
findOne(): AAA {
  return new AAA({
    date1: new Date(),
    name: 'test',
    id: 1
  });
}
```

Comment: i use to connect to database, i did like that but it can't find module 'class-transformer'
and i don't know exactly how to use it can you help me please

Comment: Well, then you just need to modify body of `findOne` method. If you have @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor) everything should work with repository. If you give us snippet of one method of controller I can modify my example.

Comment: My entity
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class AAA {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 500 })
  name: string;

  @Column()
  date1:Date; 
}

Comment: I have modified example. Take a look.

Comment: I recommend against using Moment.js